Data scraping dynamic website performance
I want to scrape a newspaper archive website (genios.de) and am facing the issue that the table of contents of versions of the website are rendered dynamically once clicked. A preview window opens and the toc can be accessed.
I am using Selenium and I am already getting the data that I want. The issue, however, is efficiency. This is because once I clicked one tile, the content is rendered and then remains there when I click further tiles. Is there a simple and efficient way to make sure that the "old" content is no longer available once I click on the new tile other than the extreme driver.refresh which would surely not be more efficient?
In its current form, with each click, the rendering as well as the extracting of the headlines takes longer. (from fractions of a second to up to two seconds)
Edit: I have shortened my question significantly to narrow it down to just this one aspect.

do you want to scrape what's inside the preview window for all the tiles?

Simple answer is: yes, there are ways to do it. But without code, url there is not answer

Used their API endpoint to fetch those data (which are opened in the preview window)
Please run this script and see if this is what you want (full details are not available since this is a paid archive app)
Code:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import quote
import pandas as pd
import concurrent.futures
import time, json, os, requests

out = []
file = 'file.csv'
issue_date = []
doc_link = []
doc_title = []
archive_link = []

def dateRange(start_date, end_date):
    start = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    end = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    date_range = pd.date_range(start,end-timedelta(days=1),freq='d')
    return date_range

def getData(urls):
    session = requests.Session()
    resp = session.get(urls).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'lxml')
    for i in soup.find_all('input'):
        data = i['data-db'].upper()
        url = f"https://www.genios.de/api/tableOfContents/{data}?useDateForTableOfContents=1"
        resp = requests.get(url).content
        json_data = json.loads(resp)
        for i in json_data['latestArticles']:
            issue_date.append(i['issueDateString'])
            doc_link.append(f"https://www.genios.de/document/{i['documentId']}")
            doc_title.append(i['documentTitle'])
            archive_link.append(f"https://www.genios.de{quote(i['archiveLink'])}")
        if not soup.find('input'):
            break

def read_csv(file, start_date, end_date):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    json_str = df.to_json(orient='records')
    json_obj = json.loads(json_str)
    for i in json_obj:
        if i['ISSUE_DATE'] in dateRange(start_date, end_date):
            print(f"--------------------\nISSUE DATE: {i['ISSUE_DATE']}\nDOCUMENT TITLE: {i['DOCUMENT_TITLE']}\nDOCUMENT LINK: {i['DOCUMENT_LINK']}\nDOCUMENT ARCHIVE LINK: {i['DOCUMENT_ARCHIVE_LINK']}")

def check_file(start_date, end_date):
    check_file_path = os.path.exists(f'./{file}')
    if check_file_path:
        read_csv(file, start_date, end_date)
        
    else:
        urls = []
        for i in range(25, 500, 25): #offset = 25,50.....n
            urls.append(f"https://www.genios.de/browse/Alle/Presse?offset={i}&partial=true&sort=BY_DATE&hasFilterList=true")
        
        #use concurrent.futures to speed up the requests process 
        
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
            future_to_url = (executor.submit(getData, url) for url in urls)
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
                try:
                    data = future.result()
                except Exception as exc:
                    data = str(type(exc))
                finally:
                    out.append(data)
        get_dict = {
            "ISSUE_DATE": issue_date,
            "DOCUMENT_TITLE": doc_title,
            "DOCUMENT_LINK": doc_link,
            "DOCUMENT_ARCHIVE_LINK": archive_link
        }
        df = pd.DataFrame(get_dict)
        df.to_csv(file, index=False)
        read_csv(file, start_date, end_date)
       
        
check_file('2024-1-1', '2024-10-31')

Output:
--------------------
ISSUE DATE: 2024-04-13
DOCUMENT TITLE: Fahrt in den Tod
DOCUMENT LINK: https://www.genios.de/document/NSA__f928bbe1f78a17fa3feee191fb17bf7c3bb75d09
DOCUMENT ARCHIVE LINK: https://www.genios.de/browse/Alle/Presse/Presse%20Deutschland/N%C3%BCrnberger%20Stadtanzeiger
--------------------
ISSUE DATE: 2024-04-13
DOCUMENT TITLE: Ohne Titel
DOCUMENT LINK: https://www.genios.de/document/NSA__b40ee7ca9b37d0bc3a6aeb5a7c4a778a7999980a
DOCUMENT ARCHIVE LINK: https://www.genios.de/browse/Alle/Presse/Presse%20Deutschland/N%C3%BCrnberger%20Stadtanzeiger
--------------------
ISSUE DATE: 2024-04-13
DOCUMENT TITLE: Was macht eigentlich der Verein "Hawelti"?
DOCUMENT LINK: https://www.genios.de/document/NSA__a9722a7f3ec06028563980949ba80f3c1e6c4d64
DOCUMENT ARCHIVE LINK: https://www.genios.de/browse/Alle/Presse/Presse%20Deutschland/N%C3%BCrnberger%20Stadtanzeiger
--------------------
ISSUE DATE: 2024-04-13
DOCUMENT TITLE: Überfälliges Erinnern
DOCUMENT LINK: https://www.genios.de/document/NSA__37872e8b8bd375b19455e366efb6a53714947933
DOCUMENT ARCHIVE LINK: https://www.genios.de/browse/Alle/Presse/Presse%20Deutschland/N%C3%BCrnberger%20Stadtanzeiger
--------------------
ISSUE DATE: 2024-04-13
DOCUMENT TITLE: Nadel und Nähkästchen
DOCUMENT LINK: https://www.genios.de/document/NSA__2e76bdfbcb41041bd5ab0b86d1c209ef063b1abe
DOCUMENT ARCHIVE LINK: https://www.genios.de/browse/Alle/Presse/Presse%20Deutschland/N%C3%BCrnberger%20Stadtanzeiger
--------------------
ISSUE DATE: 2024-04-13
DOCUMENT TITLE: Alles für die Oase vor der Haustür
DOCUMENT LINK: https://www.genios.de/document/NSA__f711c56c271bf48d0e6d688b2126e12bc08c1a64
DOCUMENT ARCHIVE LINK: https://www.genios.de/browse/Alle/Presse/Presse%20Deutschland/N%C3%BCrnberger%20Stadtanzeiger

Let me if this works for you!

This seems very nice already, but could you explain a couple of things to me, please.

Can I target specific newspapers with this code?
Can I go for specific dates as well?
How did you find the api and can I read about it somewhere on their website?

Thank you!

Answer: 1. Yes you can get the specific newspaper with the name because for example: BLIC is the sort version of  Blick durch die Wirtschaft, 2. With this API- No you can't but if you add a condition in the Python script then you can get your desired date article, 3. I used Burp suite proxy by portswigger  to capture the HTTP traffic (because I'm a bounty hunter and I use this tool daily for hunting bugs) you can also do the same thing with Chrome or Firefox: right-click --> inspect element --> network tab --> now load your site --> click each request to see what they're fetching

Thank you! Is there any chance you could point me in the right direction regarding the conditions I need to add in python?

hey I edited the code, feel free to analyze if this is what you wanted

Hi! This is working really well and fast it seems, but the output file contains only about 25000 lines. If I take all the headlines of one newspaper for one year that is already about that number so there seems to be something off here. Regardless thank you very much for your efforts! I might look deeper into the api part.

Change 500 to 550 in loop i forgot to add this while submitting the code, if you feel that something off then remove the concurrent part, i believe due fast thread some connection got timeout, to run the script please remove your file.csv from the directory where you’re running this script

Is it possible that you are running into the same issue as I am with using the api? I was able to scrape quite a lot of data (like 8 newspapers with more than 100000 lines each) but am now getting http error 500 continuoulsy. According to chatGPT this might be due to rate limiting (I know this is usually 429, but maybe they didnt set it up?)

hey you saw more than 100 thousand lines Because, at that time, the script was fetching 4 lines for each article now we move into CSV and the line is now counted as a row each row contains 4 elements of our output so 25000 is fairly enough, yeah if you see an error that may be due to rate limit

Even though I ended up adjusting your code to my needs, your pointing out the api was an insane help and also a big step in learning more about web scraping! I had no idea these apis can be seen so publicly. Thank you so much!
